# HttpClient PatchAsync fails unless I put delay before request

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I am unsure if this is a bug, or if I'm doing something wrong here. This has to be one of the weirdest bugs that I've ever come across.

I am injecting an HTTPClient into my service and doing a PatchAsync request to a third party API. However when I tried over and over to test my request, the request to the third party API would return 400 - Bad Request. I had first verified the endpoint format, headers, URL, etc. on Postman, so the content, URL, headers are all correct. I even tried copy and pasting a raw JSON string as the HTTP Content (a raw JSON string that I literally just tested on Postman successfully) and the request still returned 400.

Now here is the weird part : in an effort to debug I put a breakpoint on the line where the PatchAsync is **without changing anything in my code.** After looking through the variables and not finding anything out of the ordinary I continued my code from the breakpoint and voila! The request returns 202 when I had not changed ANYTHING in my code. That gave me an idea, which was to put

```
await Task.Delay(2000);
```

before the request and again, the request succeeded. What the heck? What am I doing wrong here?
Here is my code :

```
    public async Task UpdateQuestionAndAnsweringKbWithDBKb(QnADocumentsDTO knowledgebaseDB, string locale = "ko-kr") {
        //This PATCH request here succeeds.
        HttpContent messageBody = new StringContent("[{\"op\":\"delete\",\"value\":{\"source\":\"asdf\",\"sourceKind\":\"file\"}},{\"op\":\"delete\",\"value\":{\"source\":\"asdf\",\"sourceKind\":\"file\"}}]", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        if (locale == "en-us") {
            await _httpClient.PatchAsync(_replaceQuestionAndAnsweringBaseUrl + 
                _config.GetValue<string>("QuestionAndAnswering:QuestionAndAnswering_en") + "/sources?api-version=2021-10-01", messageBody);
        } else if (locale == "ko-kr") {
            await _httpClient.PatchAsync(_replaceQuestionAndAnsweringBaseUrl + 
                _config.GetValue<string>("QuestionAndAnswering:QuestionAndAnswering_ko") + "/sources?api-version=2021-10-01", messageBody);
        }

        List<PatchCommandQuestionAndAnswerDTO> commands = new List<PatchCommandQuestionAndAnswerDTO>();
        foreach(QnADTO qna in knowledgebaseDB.qnaDocuments) {
            if (qna.approved == true)) {
                    Dictionary<string, string> m = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                    
                    foreach(MetadataDTO d in qna.metadata) {
                        m.Add(d.name, d.value);
                    }
                    QuestionAndAnswerDTO questionAndAnswer = new QuestionAndAnswerDTO(qna.answer, qna.source, qna.questions, m);
                    PatchCommandQuestionAndAnswerDTO command = new PatchCommandQuestionAndAnswerDTO();
                    command.op = "add";
                    command.value = questionAndAnswer;
                    commands.Add(command);

            }
        }

        messageBody = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(commands,new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore }), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        Console.WriteLine(await messageBody.ReadAsStringAsync());  //I have printed the messageBody here, copy and pasted this printout into Postman and verified this content is correct
        Console.WriteLine(_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ToString()); 
        if (locale == "en-us") {
            await Task.Delay(2000);
            await _httpClient.PatchAsync(_replaceQuestionAndAnsweringBaseUrl + 
                _config.GetValue<string>("QuestionAndAnswering:QuestionAndAnswering_en") + "/qnas?api-version=2021-10-01", messageBody);
        } else if (locale == "ko-kr") {
            await Task.Delay(2000);  //The following request returns 400 if I don't put this delay here. Which makes zero sense since I print the messageBody above and await for that before sending the request.
            await _httpClient.PatchAsync(_replaceQuestionAndAnsweringBaseUrl + 
                _config.GetValue<string>("QuestionAndAnswering:QuestionAndAnswering_ko") + "/qnas?api-version=2021-10-01", messageBody);
        }
    }
```

Edit :

As @user1672994 suggested the issue was the requests were being throttled by the third party API. The code as shown above makes a first request to the third party API before immediately making another request. This resulted in the second request being throttled and returning 400, which was fixed by the delay. Everything makes sense now, I just wish the third party API had given a better response than a 400 - Bad Request which completely led me to a different direction in search for a solution.

Comment: Have you tried using a transparent proxy like Fiddler, to verify the requests are identical with and without delay?

Comment: @Marco I haven't, but the issue is definitely the messageBody. The API does not return 400 for anything else other than the messageBody if the URL is correct (which it is). Since the delay is returning 202 I am assuming the messageBody is formed correctly when there is a delay and it is either empty or not forming correctly when there is no delay. Which again, looking through my code makes zero sense considering I print out the messageBody beforehand.

Comment: Are you sure a status code 202 is what you want: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#successful_responses

Comment: @PoulBak Yes. The request is to patch a knowledgebase which can be a long running job depending on the size of the request data. This is why it returns a 202 instead of 200. I went to the third party API's site to verify the 202 request resulted in the data job being completed successfully and it did.

Comment: @JohnKim - Have the third party APIs configured with request throttling at their end? Like 1 request in particular time window e.t.c.?

Comment: Maybe you have some side effect, try logging the request body with the delay and without it. This way you will see what is the difference between the two.

Comment: _"And putting a delay wouldn't be a fix for a request throttle on their end since the request body is still the same size when I send it"_ - What does that have to do with request throttling (limiting how frequently you can make a request)?

Comment: In fact it will be better if you log the request message after the call to patch.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar I did not know what it meant by request throttling. And user1672994 was correct. The reason why putting a delay worked was because the code was attempting to call the API immediately after the first PATCH request which resulted in the request getting throttled. Case closed. Thanks for the help everyone!